# How can I display 4 lines above the matched pattern

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Here's the file **temp.file**

```
Line no1
Line no2
Line no3
Line no4
Line no5
abc
```

I am using `less temp.file|grep -i "abc"`
which prints me the line "abc".

But I want the 4 lines above it to be printed as well..

So, the desired output should be

```
Line no2
Line no3
Line no4
Line no5
abc
```

How, can I get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for that in GNU grep: `-B`

```
less temp.file | grep  -B4 -i "abc"
```

**From the Man-Page on Context Line Control:**

```
   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (--)  between  contiguous  groups  of
          matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.